# Calling Oracle stored procedure using Entity Framework with output parameter?

Tags: c#, oracle, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, oracle-manageddataaccess

I have a simple Oracle stored procedure that gets three parameters passed in, and has one output parameter:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE RA.RA_REGISTERASSET
(
    INPROJECTNAME IN VARCHAR2
    ,INCOUNTRYCODE IN VARCHAR2
    ,INLOCATION IN VARCHAR2
    ,OUTASSETREGISTERED OUT VARCHAR2
)
AS
BEGIN
  SELECT 
      INPROJECTNAME || ', ' || INLOCATION || ', ' || INCOUNTRYCODE
  INTO
      OUTASSETREGISTERED
  FROM
      DUAL;     
END RA_REGISTERASSET;
```

I am trying to use Entity Framework 6.1 to get back the `OutAssetRegistered` value, however, I get a null after calling `SqlQuery` with no exception:

```
public class CmdRegisterAssetDto
{
        public string inProjectName { get; set; }
        public string inCountryCode { get; set; }
        public string inLocation { get; set; }
        public string OutAssetRegistered { get; set; }
}
```

//------------------------------------------------------------

```
string projectName = "EXCO";
string location = "ANYWHERE";
string countryCode = "XX";

using (var ctx = new RAContext())
{
    var projectNameParam = new OracleParameter("inProjectName", OracleDbType.Varchar2, projectName, ParameterDirection.Input);
    var countryCodeParam = new OracleParameter("inCountryCode", OracleDbType.Varchar2, countryCode, ParameterDirection.Input);
    var locationParam = new OracleParameter("inLocation", OracleDbType.Varchar2, location, ParameterDirection.Input);
    var assetRegisteredParam = new OracleParameter("OutAssetRegistered", OracleDbType.Varchar2, ParameterDirection.Output);

    var sql = "BEGIN RA.RA_RegisterAsset(:inProjectName, :inCountryCode, :inLocation, :OutAssetRegistered); END;";
    var query = ctx.Database.SqlQuery<CmdRegisterAssetDto>(sql, projectNameParam, countryCodeParam, locationParam, assetRegisteredParam
    );

    assetRegistered = (string)assetRegisteredParam.Value;
}
```

I have been battling to get this to work to no avail, have checked different blogs, all the other crud operations work, can anyone please assist and direct me where I am going wrong?

Comment: I have a similar requirement were you able to get it resolved?

Comment: I'm having the same issue, please let me know if you found a solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In this case, you shouldn't be calling:

```
var query = ctx.Database.SqlQuery<CmdRegisterAssetDto>(sql, projectNameParam, countryCodeParam, locationParam, assetRegisteredParam);
```

But instead be calling:

```
var result = ctx.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(sql, projectNameParam, countryCodeParam, locationParam, assetRegisteredParam);
```

Notice that the only effective difference is that `SqlQuery<CmdRegisterAssetDto>` was replaced with `ExecuteSqlCommand`. This also means that the DTO is unnecessary. Otherwise, your code looks like it should work. Here's your original code in its entirety with the changes I mentioned:

```
string projectName = "EXCO";
string location = "ANYWHERE";
string countryCode = "XX";

using (var ctx = new RAContext())
{
    var projectNameParam = new OracleParameter("inProjectName", OracleDbType.Varchar2, projectName, ParameterDirection.Input);
    var countryCodeParam = new OracleParameter("inCountryCode", OracleDbType.Varchar2, countryCode, ParameterDirection.Input);
    var locationParam = new OracleParameter("inLocation", OracleDbType.Varchar2, location, ParameterDirection.Input);
    var assetRegisteredParam = new OracleParameter("OutAssetRegistered", OracleDbType.Varchar2, ParameterDirection.Output);

    var sql = "BEGIN RA.RA_RegisterAsset(:inProjectName, :inCountryCode, :inLocation, :OutAssetRegistered); END;";
    var result = ctx.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(sql, projectNameParam, countryCodeParam, locationParam, assetRegisteredParam);

    assetRegistered = (string)assetRegisteredParam.Value;
}
```

To prove my theory, I reproduced the null behavior that you're experiencing and then made that one change. It hung for a bit (probably to let EF kick into gear), but then executed quickly every time thereafter. In each case, I found a value waiting in the out parameter.

If anyone out there is running into trouble, there's a longhand variation that takes care of the scripting details for you:

```
string projectName = "EXCO";
string location = "ANYWHERE";
string countryCode = "XX";

using (var ctx = new RAContext())
using (var cmd = ctx.Database.Connection.CreateCommand())
{
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.CommandText = "RA.RA_REGISTERASSET";

    var projectNameParam = new OracleParameter("inProjectName", OracleDbType.Varchar2, projectName, ParameterDirection.Input);
    var countryCodeParam = new OracleParameter("inCountryCode", OracleDbType.Varchar2, countryCode, ParameterDirection.Input);
    var locationParam = new OracleParameter("inLocation", OracleDbType.Varchar2, location, ParameterDirection.Input);
    var assetRegisteredParam = new OracleParameter("OutAssetRegistered", OracleDbType.Varchar2, ParameterDirection.Output);
    cmd.Parameters.AddRange(new[] { projectNameParam, countryCodeParam, locationParam, assetRegisteredParam });

    cmd.Connection.Open();
    var result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    cmd.Connection.Close();

    assetRegistered = (string)assetRegisteredParam.Value;
}
```

As an afterthought, you technically could go with your original solution if you invoked the query immediately after (i.e. `query.FirstOrDefault()`). The return value of the query would always be null, but your out parameter would at least get populated. This is because EF queries use deferred execution.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to pass in and/or out a date:

```
        public DateTime GetDate(string dateIn)
        {
            Regex regex = new Regex(@"(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}T\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}Z)");

            if (!regex.IsMatch(dateIn))
            {
                throw new ArgumentException($"dateIn must be given in the YYYY-MM-DD\"T\"hh24:mi:ss\"Z\" format. " +
                    $"Value given: {dateIn}");
            }

            OracleParameter dateInParam = new OracleParameter("DATE_IN_", dateIn);
            createdParam.OracleDbType = OracleDbType.TimeStampTZ;
            OracleParameter dateOutParam= new OracleParameter("DATE_OUT_", OracleDbType.Date, System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output);

            var sql = "BEGIN " +
                $"Get_Date(:DATE_IN_, TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ('{dateIn}','YYYY-MM-DD\"T\"hh24:mi:ss\"Z\"'), :DATE_OUT_ ); " +
                "END;";

#pragma warning disable EF1000 // Possible SQL injection vulnerability.
            context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(sql, dateInParam, dateOutParam);
#pragma warning restore EF1000 // Possible SQL injection vulnerability.

            return (DateTime)(OracleDate)dateOutParam.Value;
        }
```