# devart web api call procedure with entity framework context

Tags: c#, oracle, asp.net-web-api, procedure, devart

I have and web api and I use entity framework but for procedure I am calling procedure like code below

```
    public List<PDS_SPR_ATAMA> GetListAtama()
    {
        List<PDS_SPR_ATAMA> result = new List<PDS_SPR_ATAMA>();
        try
        {
            var param4 = new OracleParameter("PRC", OracleDbType.Cursor, ParameterDirection.Output);
            result = _db_dev.Database.SqlQuery<PDS_SPR_ATAMA>(
            "BEGIN BMS.PA_HR_PORTAL.PR_GET_SPR_ATAMALAR(:V_PRC); end;", param4).ToList();
            return result;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return result;
        }
    }
```

as library I use

```
using Devart.Data.Oracle;
```

I take error below

> The Parameters collection only accepts
> Devart.Data.Oracle.OracleParameter type objects

How can I solve problem. Thanks in advance

Comment: From the look of it it seems your param4 is not Devart.Data.Oracle.OracleParameter, but for example System.Data.OracleClient.OracleParameter (same name, different namespace)

Comment: When I downgrade devart version to 5.0.1772.0 it worked. I need to work it for newer versions too. @Evk

Comment: Did you update all dlls/nuget packages to that new version? Devart.Data.Oracle, Devart.Data.Oracle.EFCore and so on?

Answer (score 1):

Please use Devart.Data.Oracle.OracleParameter instead of OracleParameter to make sure you are using OracleParameter from the Devart.Data.Oracle namespace.

Answer (score 0):

**You should use _db_dev.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand**. Please follow the below link. I think it will help you.

[Calling Oracle stored procedure using Entity Framework with output parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39037720/calling-oracle-stored-procedure-using-entity-framework-with-output-parameter)